# How to make a vanity top structurely sound for a vessel sink

Tags: sink

Hello everyone and thank you in advance to all that answer my question. So here is my dilemma..I recently took the sink out of my vanity in my powder room. It left a open area that I can see inside of the vanity but it also has small pieces of wood in each corner, I guess to keep the thing from falling apart. I want to build a shallow shadow box structure and then put a 12.5lb vessel sink and about a 3 pound faucet on top. My question is how can I make this structurely sound? I have thought about putting 2x4 across the top of the vanity and then placing a piece of plywood on top of that. I only have 1 1/2 inches of height available to me. The whole area is 21X30 inches. And if I use the 2x4 can I just screw it in the vanity or should I get metal brackets? If you have any additional questions just let me and I will try to explain it...thanks again!!!!

Comment: It's not clear how it's not currently "structurally sound". The weight of a countertop is usually carried mostly by the cabinet sides. Maybe photos or a sketch might clear things up.

Comment: A picture of what you have, and a sketch of what you want to do would be helpful. But It sounds like you are trying to overkill something that should actually be easy - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While a picture would be nice, I'm confident that 3/4" or even 5/8" ply, alone, will carry the load of the sink on that small of an area.